# When we put the app we created in the background after launching it on iOS, the app crashed in about 35 seconds

Tags: sdk

Please forgive me if there are strange sentences or rude expressions because it is an English translation by Google translation.

When we put the app we created in the background after launching it on iOS, the app crashed in about 35 seconds,
There is an issue that the application will be restarted when it is brought to the foreground again.
As a result of investigation, the following logs were confirmed in Xcode when the app was in the background.

"Background task still not ended after expiration handlers were called: <*UIBackgroundTaskInfo: 0x6000011db380>:
taskID = 35, taskName = MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence, creationTime = 5431 (elapsed = 25). This app will likely be terminated by the system. Call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(*:) to avoid this."

The MCSDK background task is not finished and this may cause the app to terminate.
To avoid this, call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:), but I can't find any other cause for the crash (application termination).

The current SDK version is 7.5.0, and I found an article that a similar event occurred in the 7 series version,
I upgraded to the latest version 8.0.10, but the problem did not go away.

Reference article: https://ja.firstlightsalon.in/salesforce_threads/questions/306671/ios-crash-in-sfmcnetworkrequest-with-sdk-v6-4-2

Also, considering the possibility that there was a problem with the implementation, we confirmed that the introduction and implementation were performed according to the procedure.
The implementation was done according to the manual, and there were no problems.

The features implemented in the app are:

・Receive push notifications
・Get all push notifications
・Send push notification of opening and reading

From the above, I would like to ask the following questions.

1. What is the MCSDK background task mentioned in the log?
2. The log says "To avoid this, call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:)." Does ending the task affect the operation?
3. Is there a workaround other than terminating the task?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I have similar message in debug console in simulator when app goes to background. Thanks for your help (note: IDs and URLs have been manually scrambled). 10.18.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS031014] Screen class name is empty nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C12.1.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR 54 nw_protocol_socket_reset_linger [C12.1.1:3] setsockopt SO_LINGER failed 22 Connection 12: received failure notification Connection 12: received ECONNRESET with incomplete TLS handshake - generating errSSLClosedNoNotify Connection 12: failed to connect 3:-9 816, reason -1 Connect